# OVER (ORDER BY Col) generates 'Sort' operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, query-optimization

I'm working on a query that needs to do filtering, ordering and paging according to the user's input. Now I'm testing a case that's really slow, upon inspection of the Query Plan a 'Sort' is taking 96% of the time.

The datamodel is really not that complicated, the following query should be clear enough to understand what's happening:

```
WITH OrderedRecords AS (
    SELECT 
        A.Id
        , A.col2
        , ...
        , B.Id
        , B.col1 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.col1 ASC) AS RowNumber
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON (B.SomeThing IS NULL) AND (A.BId = B.Id)
    WHERE (A.col2 IN (...)) AND (B.Id IN (...))
)
SELECT
    *
FROM OrderedRecords WHERE RowNumber Between x AND y
```

A is a table containing about 100k records, but will grow to tens of millions in the field, while B is category type table with 5 items (and this will never grow any bigger then perhaps a few more). There are clustered indexes on A.Id and B.Id.

Performance is really dreadful and I'm wondering if it's possible to remedy this somehow. If, for example, the ordering is on A.Id instead of B.col1 everything is pretty darn fast. Perhaps I can optimize B.col1 is some sort of index.

I already tried putting an index on the field itself, but this didn't help. Probably because the number of distinct items in table B is very small (in itself & compared to A).

Any ideas?

Comment: Temporary tables (those with #/##) can be faster then CTEs, they also allow indexes (so, you would put one on RowNumber column).

Comment: does it change anything with `ORDER BY B.col1, A.Id` instead of `ORDER BY B.col1 ASC` ?

Comment: @SebStuij, are you sure you join A and B on `A.Id = B.Id` and not something like `A.CategoryId = B.Id` ?

Comment: Damn them typos... You're right, it should read: AND (A.BId = B.Id)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be part of the problem:

```
   LEFT JOIN B ON (B.SomeThing IS NULL) AND (A.Id = B.Id)
    WHERE (A.col2 IN (...)) AND (B.Id IN (...)
```

Your LEFT JOIN is going to logically act like an INNER JOIN because of the WHERE clause you have in place, since only certain B.ID rows are going to be returned.  If that's your intent, then go ahead and use an inner join, which may help the optimizer realize that you are looking for a restricted number of rows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully; I used a left join, because it can happen that B.SomeThing <> NULL, in which case I do want records of A to be returned.

Comment: The WHERE clause you've specified says that you only want rows where A.ID is in some list AND B.ID is in some list. Think of it this way; you've said "get me all rows from A and matching rows from B" (in your JOIN clause), and then you've told the optimizer to only return rows from B where they match a certain list.

Comment: is B.Something a column?

Comment: Yes, and the in clause isn't over A.Id, but over some other column

Comment: @SebStuij , it is true that LEFT JOIN is useless with a B.Id IN the WHERE CLAUSE. Make it a INNER JOIN, or move the B.Id IN up into the ON CLAUSE

Comment: But, the B.Id IN isn't necessarily a part of the query. The query string is generated dynamically based on the users filtering wishes.

Comment: By the way, removing that particular clause in my tests doesn't really add anything in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try following.

For the `B` table create index:

```
create index IX_B_1 on B (col1, Id, SomeThing)
```

For the `A` table create index:

```
create index IX_A_1 on A (col2, BId) include (Id, ...)
```

In the `include` put all other columns of the table `A`, that listed in `SELECT` of `OrderedRecords` CTE.

However, as you see, index `IX_A_1` is space taking, and can take size of about table data itself.

So, as an alternative you may try omit extra columns from `include` part of the index:

```
create index IX_A_2 on A (col2, BId) include (Id)
```

but in this case you will have to slightly modify your query:

```
;WITH OrderedRecords AS (
    SELECT 
        AId = A.Id
        , A.col2
        -- remove other A columns from here
        , bid = B.Id
        , B.col1 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.col1 ASC) AS RowNumber
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON (B.SomeThing IS NULL) AND (A.BId = B.Id)
    WHERE (A.col2 IN (...)) AND (B.Id IN (...))
)
SELECT
    R.*, A.OtherColumns
FROM OrderedRecords R
    join A on A.Id = R.AId
WHERE R.RowNumber Between x AND y
```